# Можно ли каким-либо образом совместить JS и C++?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, yandex-maps-jsapi

Допустим есть приложение на Qt и хотел бы встроить в него карту Yandex (Js Api). Можно ли это как-то провернуть? Ну вообще можно же как-то подружить JS и C++?

Comment: Ну Райан Далл как-то подружил :))

Comment: `QWebView` спасёт отца русской демократии

Comment: Последние версии Qt добавили полную поддержку JS в Qml, если я ничего не путаю